# Image show with custom size in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, python-imaging-library

How can I change the default resolution to an image presented in a jupyter notebook?

Code example (using IPython.display):

```
from PIL import Image
from IPython.display import display

im = Image.open("monique.png")
im2 = im.rotate(95)

display(im2)
```

I would like to customize the size of the output image (to produce an output like a small 300x300 image). The display function does not allow to choose the output resolution with a command like `display(im2, 300,300)`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Widgets interface provided by `ipywidgets`

```py
import ipywidgets as widgets

file = open("images/WidgetArch.png", "rb")
image = file.read()
widgets.Image(
    value=image,
    format='png',
    width=300,
    height=400,
)
```

You can find that code block on the site: https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20List.html#Image

Comment: I am trying to use widgets now as you recommended. Thanks